# Can't install command-not-found on pip

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip

I wanna install the pip package command-not-found which is defined in my requirements.txt like this: `command-not-found==0.3` on my Ubuntu machine but i get this error:

```
ERROR: No matching distribution found for command-not-found==0.3
```

I heard that there is an apt package `python-commandnotfound` but i can't install that too

```
E: Unable to locate package python-commandnotfound
```

I also tried `apt search` with an `apt update` but both returned nothing. I also am getting the same error in my GitHub Actions and at work

Comment: Are you not seeing it through apt with `apt-cache search command-not-found ` -- `apt-get install python-commandnotfound` ?

Comment: @JNevill nope same return there

Comment: `apt-get install python3-commandnotfound` maybe and/or `apt-get install command-not-found`

Comment: I see a pip package named `commandnotfound`, without the dashes.  Current version is 0.5.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the problem actually it was a pretty stupid mistake  
The issue was that i was creating the `requirements.txt` but forgot to activate my `venv`.

Thank you for the suggestions tho

So always use a venv people

Comment: You may want to fix the spelling of "requirments.txt", otherwise it won't work either.

Answer (score -1):

Please check if you are using the correct user for the command. Maybe try as an administrator.

```
sudo apt-get update
```